# Cannot see created SQL Server tables in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql-server-spatial

I have a MSSQL 2012 database that I can connect to from ArcGIS using 'Add Database Connection'. In this database I have a spatial table that I can see and open in ArcGIS, however when I create a table using 'SELECT * INTO newtable from..' I cannot see the new table in ArcGIS. I can see the new table in Management studio and it has all the columns and data. The only difference I can see from the old table is that there is no Primary key. If I set this it makes no difference and I still cannot see the table in ArcGIS. Here is the SQL script I'm using:

```
USE TrafficData;

IF object_id('TrafficData.dbo.a') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE TrafficData.dbo.a;

SELECT * 

INTO TrafficData.dbo.a

FROM AMBASE_V15LINKS_POLYLINE;
```

Comment: Desktop filters out 'aN', 'dN', 'fN', and 'sN' tables. If you use a less trivial name it will be less likely to be ignored as an implementation support table.

Comment: @Vince that looks well worth writing up as a short answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ArcGIS Desktop "opens" a connection, it uses the appropriate database technique to generate a list of tables, but, depending on release and database, it also filters out "hidden" names, among them the "F*n*" and "S*n*" used for SDEBINARY storage, the "A*n*" and "D*n*" used for versioning, the "*_H" archive history tables, and all the other common patterns, using either a complex sequence of `AND` terms or local comparison functions on the way to generating the table list.

In your case, you've generated a table named `A`, which is close enough to `A1` for it to be captured by the filter functions.  I would recommend you use longer and/or more descriptive scratch table names, like `FOO` or `TMP_AMBASE_V15LINKS`.  The benefit of using names not likey to conflict with names generated by ArcGIS is a reduced probability of accidently `DROP`-ping tables needed to implement the geodatabase (and thereby corrupting your geodatabase instance).